# I have the parts for Filler (Buildcraft), but it won't craft!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have everything I need to make a Filler, and in the correct places, but it won't allow me to craft it. When I click on the recipe (on the right in the screenshot) it has the exact same thing, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong!

I am on a multiplayer server (with one other friend) using the Direwolf20 ModPack from Feed the Beast. My computer is a mac. The recipe has been checked and it is the right one.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for you not been able to craft would be that the crafting recipe has been disable by the servers owner. The most common reason for disabling them as if you played them round spawn or someone house it could be very destructive. Your best bet is to contact the servers admin.

Comment: I'll give that a try then, cheers mate